# Why does my program print "This is a prime." twice?

Tags: python

I wrote a program to determine whether or not a number is a prime. The program works, except that it prints out the final statement twice, which I don't want. I'm fairly new to Python so please give any advice on making my code more efficient.

```
def user(text = "Give me a number.\n"):
    return int(input(text))
number = user()
list = range(1, number + 1)
divisor = []
for element in list:
    divide = number % element
    if divide == 0:
        divisor.append(element)
for element in divisor:
    if len(divisor) > 2:
        print ("This isn't a prime.")
        user("Give me another number.\n")
    else:
        print ("This is a prime.")
```

Comment: Because you print `This is a prime.` every time `len(divisor)` is 2, 1 or 0. If that happens twice, then that means `len(divisor)` is exactly 2.

Comment: This is a scenario where stepping through it line-by-line in a debugger, and looking at the state of all the variables, is very useful. If you don't already know how to do that, I'd recommend using an IDE like PyCharm and learning how to do it, since it's an essential tool.

Comment: Note: `user(...)` returns a value. You ignored that value when you call `user(...)` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but don't use `list` as a variable name in Python. It's a builtin name.

Comment: you have [1, number] in divisor and iterate through that. DONT loop on the list, does not make sense, just remove the for element in divisor and you are fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend that you learn basic debugging techniques.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
If nothing else, remove overhead code and insert a couple of strategic `print` statements to trace the control and data flows.  For instance:

```
number = 7      # For debugging, pick a single problem number.
divisor = [] 

for element in range(1, number + 1):
    divide = number % element
    if divide == 0:
        divisor.append(element)

print(number, "has divisors", divisor) 

for element in divisor: 
    if len(divisor) > 2:
        print ("This isn't a prime.")
        # user("Give me another number.\n")
    else:
        print ("This is a prime.", element)
```

Output:

```
7 has divisors [1, 7]
This is a prime. 1
This is a prime. 7
```

You can see the problem now:

1. You've solved a larger problem: finding all divisors of a number
2. Your reporting -- supposedly a simple yes/no determination -- repeats the decision for *every* divisor, rather than just once.

For instance, given `number = 12`, the code produces

```
12 has divisors [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
This isn't a prime.
This isn't a prime.
This isn't a prime.
This isn't a prime.
This isn't a prime.
This isn't a prime.
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Following the points `blue_note` and `Martijn` made, simplify your lower code: remove the `for` to avoid multiple outputs, and remove the extra call that you don't use.  If you want to repeat the process, you'll want to wrap the entire program in a loop, not merely grab more input.

```
if len(divisor) > 2:
    print ("This isn't a prime.")
else:
    print ("This is a prime.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `for element in divisor`. The way it is now, if the number has `n` divisors, you print the message `n` times.

Also, it makes more sense to make the range `range(2, n)` and break your loop the first time you find a zero modulo. Something like

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Side note: you don't need to check up to `n-1`, it's enough to only check for numbers up to `n**2`